# Using spearman's rho in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, correlation, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to calculate the spearman rho to evaluate 3 non linear dimensionality reduction techniques. Thus, I am using `scipy.stats.stats.spearmanr(features,comp)` where features is the original matrix of the set of features and components is the matrix the comp generated by the dimensional reduction techniques.

However, this is returning a matrix, although according to what I understand from the literature in the figure below, only one value should be returned

[image: Spearman Rho used to compare dimensionality redcution technique].

The Author is then reporting these coefficients below( one figure per dim. reduction technique):
[image]

I am using the wrong function for misunderstanding the literature, please?  Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html), it returns 2 things: correlation (Spearman correlation matrix or correlation coefficient (if only 2 variables are given as parameters. Correlation matrix is square with length equal to total number of variables (columns or rows) in a and b combined.) and associated p-value. So based on your input, it can return a matrix. If it is not clear, providing some code will help us answering this question further.